# How to access SNR diagnostics on a Linux based DSL modem

Tags: linux, router, modem, adsl, adsl2+

I have an Asus DSL-N14U modem, which - when connected to its web admin user interface - shows a pretty useful graph similar to the frequency spectrum on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line. A quick look at the graph shows there's more than just one Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR) to think about; in fact there's one SNR per "bin" across the ADSL frequency range. A second graph shows how many bits each "bin" is configured to receive to make best use of the SNR.

However, despite its wealth of information, the web page makes no mention of the single SNR figure that my other ADSL modems have shown on their own web pages. Nor does it show the sync rate (or total number of bits across all of the bins). It's more of a visual aid than something that could be used for diagnosing problems.

My question is twofold, assuming that I have access to the Linux terminal on a modem (via SSH, usually):
1) where would I look on the modem's file system for this raw information so maybe I can work out the sync rate (or aggregate SNR) myself? 
2) is it possible that other non-Asus modems also expose raw statistics about the bins' SNR and bits, and simply don't display them on their web admin pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It totally depends on the modem hardware and the software installed on the modem. Every manufacturer does this differently.

If you get `ssh` access, work your way through the file system; usually there's a place were skeletons of the web-pages you see are stored, and from these you can sometimes work out how to access this information. But often it's not obvious, and needs a bit of perseverance.

2) It's totally possible; personally, I only know modems (Fritzboxes) which do have SNR bins.

What happens in your modem is that there is a second, dedicated CPU (often a DSP variety) that runs the signal processing necessary for DSL communication. Depending on how the signal-processing software works, it can communicate a lot of information about the signal, or little.

Comment: After a little reverse engineering on my ASUS DSL-N14U, I found /tmp/var/tmp contained three "spectrum-*" files with SNR and BPC bins, which I was able to interpret. I did not find the application that was creating these files, but the ps command showed a running application named "spectrum" that may be relevant.